# Multi variable gradient descent

Tags: python, machine-learning, linear-regression, gradient-descent

I am learning `gradient descent` for calculating coefficients. Below is what I am doing:

```
#!/usr/bin/Python

 import numpy as np


   # m denotes the number of examples here, not the number of features
 def gradientDescent(x, y, theta, alpha, m, numIterations):
     xTrans = x.transpose()
     for i in range(0, numIterations):
        hypothesis = np.dot(x, theta)
        loss = hypothesis - y
        # avg cost per example (the 2 in 2*m doesn't really matter here.
        # But to be consistent with the gradient, I include it)
        cost = np.sum(loss ** 2) / (2 * m)
        #print("Iteration %d | Cost: %f" % (i, cost))
        # avg gradient per example
        gradient = np.dot(xTrans, loss) / m
        # update
        theta = theta - alpha * gradient
     return theta

 X = np.array([41.9,43.4,43.9,44.5,47.3,47.5,47.9,50.2,52.8,53.2,56.7,57.0,63.5,65.3,71.1,77.0,77.8])
 y = np.array([251.3,251.3,248.3,267.5,273.0,276.5,270.3,274.9,285.0,290.0,297.0,302.5,304.5,309.3,321.7,330.7,349.0])
 n = np.max(X.shape)
 x = np.vstack([np.ones(n), X]).T      
 m, n = np.shape(x)
 numIterations= 100000
 alpha = 0.0005
 theta = np.ones(n)
 theta = gradientDescent(x, y, theta, alpha, m, numIterations)
 print(theta)
```

Now my above code works fine. If I now try multiple variables and replace `X` with `X1` like the following:

```
  X1 = np.array([[41.9,43.4,43.9,44.5,47.3,47.5,47.9,50.2,52.8,53.2,56.7,57.0,63.5,65.3,71.1,77.0,77.8], [29.1,29.3,29.5,29.7,29.9,30.3,30.5,30.7,30.8,30.9,31.5,31.7,31.9,32.0,32.1,32.5,32.9]])
```

then my code fails and shows me the following error:

```
  JustTestingSGD.py:14: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in square
  cost = np.sum(loss ** 2) / (2 * m)
  JustTestingSGD.py:19: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in subtract
  theta = theta - alpha * gradient
  [ nan  nan  nan]
```

Can anybody tell me how can I do `gradient descent` using `X1`? My expected output using `X1` is:

```
[-153.5 1.24 12.08]
```

I am open to other Python implementations also. I just want the `coefficients (also called thetas)` for `X1` and `y`.

Comment: try your `X = np.array([41.9,43.4,43.9,44.5,47.3,47.5,47.9,50.2,52.8,53.2,56.7,57.0,63.5,65.3,71.1,77.0,77.8])[:, np.newaxis]` & `y` as well with [this  implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17784587/gradient-descent-using-python-and-numpy/36390025#36390025) of *Gradient Descent* & `maxIteration = 1000000`, & `lr = 0.0001` in order to get `w=[[152.9851407 ] [  2.44436124]]`

Answer (score 3):

The problem is in your algorithm not converging. It diverges instead. The first error:

```
JustTestingSGD.py:14: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in square
cost = np.sum(loss ** 2) / (2 * m)
```

comes from the problem that at some point calculating the square of something is impossible, as the 64-bit floats cannot hold the number (i.e. it is > 10^309).

```
JustTestingSGD.py:19: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in subtract
theta = theta - alpha * gradient
```

This is only a consequence of the error before. The numbers are not reasonable for calculations.

You can actually see the divergence by uncommenting your debug print line. The cost starts to grow, as there is no convergence.

If you try your function with `X1` and a smaller value for alpha, it converges.

Comment: If, I compute `X1` with `alpha = 0.0001` then it converges and I get the following result: `[ 0.92429681  1.80242842  6.07549978]` but I am expecting something like `[-153.5 1.24 12.08]`. How can I get the desired result?

Answer (score 0):

1). use [scaling/normalization](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/315048/347139) for faster convergence of gradient descent

2). decrease learning_rate

3). exit loop according tolerance_param

```
# adopted from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17784587/gradient-descent-using-python-and-numpy
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

   # m denotes the number of examples here, not the number of features
def gradientDescent(x, y, theta, alpha, m, numIterations):
     xTrans = x.T
     theta_prev= theta
     cost_history = []

     for i in range(0, numIterations):
        Y_pred = np.dot(x, theta)
        loss = Y_pred - y
        # for the conveniences of further derivation of squared error cost: 1/(2m)*loss**2 derivative becomes 1/m*loss
        squared_error_cost = (1 / (2 * m)) * np.sum((Y_pred - y) ** 2)

        #print("Iteration %d | Cost: %f" % (i, cost))
        # avg gradient per example

        # compute the derivative for weight[i]:
        # Hint: the derivative of square root is = 2 * dot product of feature_column  and errors.
        # When you differentiate the error with respect to theta, you get X*(X*theta.T-y)
        gradient = 1/m * x.T.dot(loss)
##        print(gradient)

        # update
        # theta = theta - alpha * gradient
        theta[0] = theta[0] - (alpha * ((1/m) *
                                              np.sum(Y_pred - y)))
        theta[1] = theta[1] - (alpha * ((1/m) *
                                              np.sum((Y_pred - y) * x.T)))
        cost_history.append( squared_error_cost )

        # accuracy
        p, e = Y_pred, y
        n = len(Y_pred)
        acc= 1-sum(
                [
                    abs(p[i]-e[i])/e[i]
                    for i in range(m)
                    if e[i] != 0]
            )/m
        if i%100==0: print(f'at {i}-th step accuracy is {acc}')

        # Check for tolerance .....
        if(gradient[0] + theta_prev[0] <= 10**(-6)) and (gradient[1] + theta_prev[1] <= 10**(-6)): break
        theta_prev = theta
     return cost_history, theta, acc

X = np.array([41.9,43.4,43.9,44.5,47.3,47.5,47.9,50.2,52.8,53.2,56.7,57.0,63.5,65.3,71.1,77.0,77.8])
y = np.array([251.3,251.3,248.3,267.5,273.0,276.5,270.3,274.9,285.0,290.0,297.0,302.5,304.5,309.3,321.7,330.7,349.0])

# NORMALIZATION .....
X = (X-X.min())/(X.max()-X.min())
y = (y-y.min())/(y.max()-y.min())

plt.plot(X,y)
plt.show()

# Add a bias feature (constant 1) to the input matrix.....
n = np.max(X.shape)
X_bias = np.vstack([np.ones(n), X]).T

m, n = np.shape(X_bias)
##print(m)    # 17
numIterations= 1000
alpha = 0.1
theta = np.ones(n)

cost_hist, theta, acc = gradientDescent(X_bias, y, theta, alpha, m, numIterations)  
print("theta: ", theta)
print("Accuracy: ", acc)

yhat=  theta@X_bias.T
print('yhat', yhat)
plt.plot(X, y, 'bo-', X_bias[:,1], yhat, 'k-')
plt.legend(['Data', 'Actual Relationship'])
plt.show()

# plot grad
x = [i for i in range(1, len(cost_hist)+1)]
plt.plot(x, cost_hist)
plt.xlabel('Iteration')
plt.ylabel('Cost')
plt.title('Cost History during Gradient Descent')
plt.show()
```

p.s. for multivariable - see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34705494/simple-linear-regression-in-python?rq=3) or [here](https://medium.com/@Coursesteach/machine-learning-part-17-gradient-descent-for-multiple-variables-1048c2ea5301)