# relation of loss to features in gradient descent calculation

Tags: java, gradient-descent

My teammates and I are trying to code up an implementation of gradient descent and I think we're pretty close

We've (attempted) to follow the steps associated with the first answer to [**this question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17784587/gradient-descent-using-python-and-numpy/17796231#17796231), namely:

**1.** Calculate the hypothesis h = X * theta

**2.** Calculate the loss = h - y and maybe the squared cost (loss^2)/2m

**3.** Calculate the gradient = X' * loss / m

**4.** Update the parameters theta = theta - alpha * gradient

But as you can see from the missing code there, we're at a bit of a loss as to how to calculate the gradient, have we set it up correctly?

How to execute that calculation?

What is the difference between X' and X?

```
  double loss, cost, hypothesis;
  int p, iteration;

  iteration = 0;
  do 
  {
    iteration++;
    cost = 0.0;
    //loop through all instances (complete one epoch)
    for (p = 0; p < number_of_files__train; p++) 
    {

      hypothesis = calculateHypothesis( weights, feature_matrix__train, p, globo_dict_size );

      loss = outputs__train[p] - hypothesis;

      for (int i = 0; i < globo_dict_size; i++) 
      {

        weights[i] += LEARNING_RATE * loss * feature_matrix__train[p][i] * calculateGradent( weights, i, number_of_files__train, loss );

      }

      //summation of squared error (error value for all instances)
      cost += (loss*loss);
    }
    cost = cost/(2 * number_of_files__train);

  } 
  while(cost != 0 && iteration<=MAX_ITER);


}

static double calculateHypothesis( double weights[], double[][] feature_matrix, int file_index, int globo_dict_size )
{
  //# m denotes the number of examples here, not the number of features

 double sum = 0.0;

 for (int i = 0; i < globo_dict_size; i++) 
 {
   sum += ( weights[i] * feature_matrix[file_index][i] );
 }
 //bias
 sum += weights[ globo_dict_size ];

   return sigmoid(sum);
}

private static double sigmoid(double x)
{
    return 1 / (1 + Math.exp(-x));
}

static double calculateGradent( double weights[], int i, int number_of_files__train, double loss )
{
  return weights[i] * loss / number_of_files__train;
}
```

Comment: X is a matrix of inputs, whereas X' is the transpose of that matrix, viz. if X is a row matrix of the inputs, X' is a column matrix of those same inputs. From the example you linked x is X, and xTrans is X'. You can see that they generate xTrans by performing the transpose() operation on x.

Comment: then why the hell would it matter if i do operations on the weights as a column or as a row? it's just a 1D array, why does that matter at all?

Comment: In matrix algebra, the dimension of the array makes a lot of difference when performing dot and cross products.

Comment: but for a 1D array? it's the same isn't it?

Comment: In the scalar case, it's the same thing. But to be a valid gradient descent algorithm you can't incrementally update theta parameters one partial derivative at a time; you must calculate all partials, then update all thetas at once. calculateGradient should produce a vector the same dimension and rank as theta (weights), per gradient[i] = weights[i] * loss/m; where m is the rank of weights vector.

Comment: what do you mean by rank? the index?

Comment: [Matrix rank](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_%28linear_algebra%29), the number of elements in the vector.