# constrained or projected gradient descent using any python library?

Tags: python, mathematical-optimization

I have this optimization problem and I wonder any function in any python library can solve it? Say I want to minimize `f(x)` by gradient descent. x is a vector of say 3 dimensions, `x=(x1,x2,x3)`. The constraint is `x1>0, x2>0, x3>0`, and `x1+x2+x3=1`. Any function can solve this constrained gradient descent? Thank you.

Comment: this post might be of some help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17784587/gradient-descent-using-python-and-numpy

Comment: also, scikit-learn has functionality to do SGD http://scikit-learn.org/0.11/modules/sgd.html

Comment: Can you add an example in your question?