# Gradient Descent & linear regression - Code not converging

Tags: python, machine-learning

I'm trying to implement the gradient descent algorithm from scratch on a toy problem. My code always returns a vector of `NaN`'s:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

np.random.seed(45)
x = np.linspace(0, 1000, num=1000)
y = 3*x + 2 + np.random.randn(len(x))

# sklearn output - This works (returns intercept = 1.6, coef = 3)
lm = LinearRegression()
lm.fit(x.reshape(-1, 1), y.reshape(-1, 1))
print("Intercept = {:.2f}, Coef = {:.2f}".format(lm.coef_[0][0], lm.intercept_[0]))

# BGD output
theta = np.array((0, 0)).reshape(-1, 1)
X = np.hstack([np.ones_like(x.reshape(-1, 1)), x.reshape(-1, 1)]) # [1, x]
Y = y.reshape(-1, 1) # Column vector
alpha = 0.05
for i in range(100):
    # Update: theta <- theta - alpha * [X.T][X][theta] - [X.T][Y]
    h = np.dot(X, theta) # Hypothesis
    loss = h - Y
    theta = theta - alpha*np.dot(X.T, loss)
theta
```

The `sklearn` part runs fine, so I must be doing something wrong in the for loop. I've tried various different `alpha` values and none of them converge.

The problem is `theta` keeps getting bigger and bigger throughout the loop, and eventually becomes too big for python to store.

Here's a contour plot of the cost function:

```
J = np.dot((np.dot(X, theta) - y).T, (np.dot(X, theta) - y))
plt.contour(J)
```

[image]

Clearly there's no minimum here. Where have I gone wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In the theta update, the second term should be divided by the size of the training set. More details are there: [gradient descent using python and numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17784587/gradient-descent-using-python-and-numpy)