# Python gradient descent not converge

Tags: python, machine-learning, linear-regression, gradient-descent

So I'm a newbie to machine-learning and i have been trying to implement gradient descent. My code seems to be right (I think) but it didn't converge to the global optimum.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def AddOnes(matrix):
    one = np.ones((matrix.shape[0], 1))
    X_bar = np.concatenate((one, matrix), axis=1)
    return X_bar


# Load data
df = pd.read_excel("Book1.xlsx", header=3)
X = np.array([df['Height']]).T
y = np.array([df['Weight']]).T

m = X.shape[0]
n = X.shape[1]
iterations = 30

# Build X_bar
X = AddOnes(X)

# Gradient descent
alpha = 0.00003
w = np.ones((n+1,1))
for i in range(iterations):
    h = np.dot(X, w)
    w -= alpha/m * np.dot(X.T, h-y)

print(w)

x0 = np.array([np.linspace(145, 185, 2)]).T
x0 = AddOnes(x0)
y0 = np.dot(x0, w)
x0 = np.linspace(145, 185, 2)

# Visualizing
plt.plot(X, y, 'ro')
plt.plot(x0, y0)
plt.axis([140, 190, 40, 80])
plt.xlabel("Height(cm)")
plt.ylabel("Weight(kg)")
plt.show()
```

[Visualizing data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M8GJy.png)

Comment: What's the question? There is no guarantee that GD will converge to the global optimum.

Comment: Getting to the global optima requires you to tune the two hyperparameters: the learning rate (alpha) and the number of iterations, have you done this?

Comment: I think with just 2 features there should be just 1 optimum, isn't it ? Or am I wrong ?

Comment: There can be many local optima depending on the data.  Consider the function sin(x)*sin(y) for instance.

Comment: It may help to start by fitting two data points to a straight line, and after that works then try something more complex.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [gradient descent using python and numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17784587/gradient-descent-using-python-and-numpy)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using Linear Regression with a single neuron, a single neuron can only learn a straight line irrespective of the dataset you provide, where W acts as slope , your network has learnt optimal W for your X such that WX gives minimal error.

The scatter plot (red dot) of the output shows your dataset values, you can observe that , the dataset is not linear, so even if you train 1M times, the algorithm will never converge. But the learnt function is optimal for sure, as it is a straight line that has minimal error.

So , I recommed you to use multiple layers with non-liner activations like ReLu and Sigmoid. Use linear activation at output as you are predicting a real number.