# Scikit - Linear Regression - Extracting Metrics

Tags: python, scikit-learn, iteration, linear-regression

- Python 3
- scikit-learn-0.23.1
- numpy-1.18.4
- scipy-1.4.1

Is it possible to extract the number of iterations it took to fit the regression model (by Gradient Descent)? Aside from the general model evaluation metrics, I don't see anything related to iteration number.

```
regressor = LinearRegression()  
regressor.fit(xtr, ytr)

print('Mean Absolute Error:', metrics.mean_absolute_error(yt, y_pred))  
print('Mean Squared Error:', metrics.mean_squared_error(yt, y_pred))  
print('Root Mean Squared Error:', np.sqrt(metrics.mean_squared_error(yt, y_pred)))
```

Scikit [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html) showing all possible metric modules

Comment: I don't think there are any iterations. Solving the linear regression problem is solving OLS which has a closed form and is calculated using SVD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Pointed out by **Gilad**, no iterations are involved to calculate the linear regression problem using OLS . I am guessing here that you are trying to achieve the *linear regression model using Gradient Descent*. For the later one, number of iterations are defined prior the execution.

So to use the **Gradient Descent**, you can manually write the [algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17784587/12210002) ([Another link](https://towardsdatascience.com/implement-gradient-descent-in-python-9b93ed7108d1)) or you can use the [Ridge](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.Ridge.html#sklearn.linear_model.Ridge) Regression or [Lasso](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.Lasso.html#sklearn.linear_model.Lasso) Regression from the Sklearn. Here there is an **n_iter paramter** by which you can achieve the number of iterations it took to determine the coefs.

> **class sklearn.linear_model.Ridge**(alpha=1.0, *, fit_intercept=True, normalize=False, copy_X=True, max_iter=None, tol=0.001, solver='auto', random_state=None)
>
> Attributes
>
> **n_iter** : _None or ndarray of shape (n_targets,)
> Actual number of iterations for each target. Available only for sag and lsqr solvers. Other solvers will return None.

**Note** : You can define the **solver** as `sag or saga` to use the gradient Descent method.

Comment: Yes, apologies. Should have stated gradient descent - Thank you!

Comment: No issues :)..Glad it helped